# Remove diacritics (accents) only in the first parameter of awk command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a main shell that reformat text from a source to a target file :

Source :

```
Libelléacte;CHAR(20);Libellé de l'acte;
```

Target :

```
 * Libellé de l'acte.
   
    05 Libelléacte PIC X(20).
```

What i want i to remove diacritics only for the first parameter. I tried to convert my file to ascii//TRANSLIT//IGNORE with iconv command but it removes all diacritics and this is not what i want.

This is my reformat code :

```
for f in $TEMP_DIRECTORY 

do 
    b=$(basename "$f")
    echo "Generating $f file in copy.."; 
    awk -F ';' '
toupper($1)=="TABLE" {printf "01 %s.\n\n", $2; next} 
toupper($1)=="EXTRACTION" {printf "01 %s.\n\n", $2; next} 
{
  result = $2
  if ($2 ~ /^Numérique [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/) {
    nr=split($2,a,"[ .]")
    result = "PIC 9(" a[2] ")"
    if (nr == 3) {
      result = result ".v9(" a[3] ")"
    }    
  }
  sub(/CHAR/,"PIC X", result);
  sub(/Char/,"PIC X", result);
  sub(/char/,"PIC X", result);
  sub(/Entier/,"PIC 9(9)", result);
  sub(/entier/,"PIC 9(9)", result);
  gsub(/user/,"user-field");
  gsub(/User/,"user-field");
  gsub("/","_");
  printf "   * %s.\n\n     05 %s %s.\n\n", $3, $1, result;
}' "$f" > "$TARGET_DIRECTORY/${b%%.*}.cpy"
done
```

I need to change only the first parameter so i can have this output :

```
 * Libellé de l'acte.

    05 Libelleacte PIC X(20).
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all diacritics in a iconv to utf8 conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70656878/how-to-remove-all-diacritics-in-a-iconv-to-utf8-conversion)

Comment: Please do not repeat same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70656878/how-to-remove-all-diacritics-in-a-iconv-to-utf8-conversion

Comment: Deleted it, the question had no answers

Comment: _I have a main shell_ : What is a **main shell**?

Comment: _only for the first parameter_  : In the script you posted, you don't access **any parameter at all**, so I don't get what you mean by 1st parameter. You would at least have to show how you invoke your script.

Comment: Please create and [edit] your question to show a [mcve] that's **just** about the problem you're asking for help with. Right now whatever problem you have and whatever code you've tried to solve it with are buried in a bunch of extraneous code/data. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would use `cut` to get the first parameter before the semicolon, then `iconv` to transliterate into *ASCII*, and finally `tr` to remove the non-alphanumerics by deleting the `[:punct:]` POSIX character class.

```sh
cat test | cut -d \; -f 1 | iconv -f UTF-8  -t ASCII//TRANSLIT | tr -d "[:punct:]"
```

Answer (score 1):

My original answer below is calling `iconv` once per line of input, this would be much more efficient:

```
$ iconv -f utf8 -t ascii//ignore file |
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1; next} {$1=a[FNR]; print}' - file
Libellacte;CHAR(20);Libellé de l'acte;
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ paste -d';' <(cut -d';' -f1 file | iconv -f utf8 -t ascii//ignore) <(cut -d';' -f2- file)
Libellacte;CHAR(20);Libellé de l'acte;
```

or if you always know the number of input fields:

```
$ iconv -f utf8 -t ascii//ignore file | paste -d';' - file | cut -d';' -f1,6-
Libellacte;CHAR(20);Libellé de l'acte;
```

Lots of options.

Change the `iconv` command to be whatever you already know it should be (given you say in your question `I tried to convert my file to ascii//TRANSLIT//IGNORE with iconv command but it removes all diacritics`) if the above isn't the right call to it.

---

Original answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while IFS=';' read -r f1 rest; do
    printf '%s;%s\n' "$(iconv -f utf8 -t ascii//ignore <<<"$f1")" "$rest"
done < file
Libellacte;CHAR(20);Libellé de l'acte;
```